# Propert file is not loading properly

Tags: java, selenium

Getting `NullPointerException` when  running all my script in the middle. I have `xpath` written in the property file and I'm loading the property file in `BeforeSuite`. The element will be present and the page is also present. Getting `null` in locator.

Comment: Now, it's the time to read the guide for asking questions. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 0):

may be your property file is not giving the exact value of you element.
try calling this function by providing the property name.

```
public static String getProperty(String propertyname)
    {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(("path of your property file"));

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty(propertyname));
        //Return the property value
        return prop.getProperty(propertyname);

    }
```